# ajax-updatepanel file download problem

Tags: .net, download

I have a gridview inside an update panel which holds the list of uploaded files to application. I want, when a row is selected, on selectedIndexChanged event to return the file to be downloaded

here is the code

string path = MyFiles.Rows[filesGrid.SelectedIndex]["FilePath"].ToString();

```
        FileStream fl = null;
        try
        {
            fl = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fl.Name);
            byte[] buff = new byte[fl.Length];
            fl.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            Response.BinaryWrite(buff);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Unable to download the file";
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fl != null)
                fl.Close();
        }
```

When I click select, I receive a javascript error "Error parsing near '%PDF-1.4%?? 2294 0'" and nothing is returned.

Has anybody faced this problem or does anybody know any possible solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial solution here

http://tgynther.blogspot.com/2009/02/aspnet-updatepanel-and-responsewrite.html

however, if you have one async and one sync trigger then it doesn't work

with one sync trigger, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's been over a year, but this might help someone else:

I solved my problem (which I think it could be the same as yours) adding two different buttons, one inside the update panel and one outside of it, but hidden. The user presses the one inside the update panel and if everything is okay, then also executes the following code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(SpecimenTestExport), "fireExport", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.btnSecondButton, ""), true);
```

thus causing the second button to fire as soon as the async postback is finished.

Hope this helps someone!